# loops! infinite inputs and keeping track of how many inputs were made

Tags: java, loops, input

Write a java program to accept an unlimited # of double type (variable) expense records with description.

Mean time list in console O/P of the same, and accumulate the total # of entries.

heres my code I have so far

```
public class Quizz {

    public double expense;
    public double totalExpenses;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Quizz expenses = new Quizz();
        Scanner intScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an expense");
            expenses.expense = intScan.nextInt();
        }
        while (proceed);

        System.out.println("done counting");
    }

}
```

Comment: where you have defined `proceed` ?

Comment: So you have some code, but what is your question?

Comment: you should call intScan.nextDouble(), as you want to get a double value

Comment: Also you need to actually accumulate the values returned. All this is doing is replacing the expense.expense with the latest int.

Comment: i came across another post that had me actually use the do while loop. I'm unsure which loop style would be the best choice here but thats how he had it setup. i didn't know i had to define it, very new to this

Comment: okay so how would i accumulate the values returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class definition here is rather weird. You don't really need a class, just a main method to do what you want:

```
    Scanner doubleScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double runningTotal = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter an amount (-1 to exit): ");
        double expense = doubleScan.nextDouble();
        if (expense != -1) runningTotal += expense;
    } while (expense != -1);
    System.out.println("Total: " + runningTotal);
```

Comment: question if i wanted the command to exit be a string ... for example the word "done" and the program would end when they typed done would i be able to do that. And thank you!!! this was actually very helpful. i have to figure out how I'm going to add the actual number of inputs the user put in and display it in the O/P

Comment: The issue becomes the scanner, then. The scanner is expecting the user to give a double. You could, if you wanted to, change the scanner so it gets strings (`String value = doubleScan.next()`), then check to see if it is a number or a word, and act upon that.